# React Navigator and React Native Interactable libraries

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to use ReactNavigator (https://reactnavigation.org) in pair with ReactNative Interactable(https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable) for animated transiotion between Navigator states ?

Has anyone tried this ?

In general I need to create a component, which takes routes config like StackNavigator proposes from React Navigator library and this component should gets left/right/top/bottom screens views and show then on swipe from  left/right/top/bottom sides of the phone respectively.

So StackNavigator is suitable for me. But I need to switch between routes with screen custom animation. And I need to has a possibility to swipe from the any side of the phone device!

Help please!! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, we are not here to write your code for you. Please show us what you've tried and tell us what isn't working, and we'll help you from there. If you need to ask about methods for doing things, you should ask that in a programming forum or chat room.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I tried to use StackNavigator from [ReactNavigator library](http://reactnavigator.org):
`...
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
...`
And HomeScreen is a component wrapped to the **Interactable.View** tag from the [RNI library](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable).

Then I need to add toutes for the navigator and animate them. But I don't know how should I do this.